# Is it possible to install a Progressive Web App within an iframe?

Tags: iframe, progressive-web-apps

I have a website. Let's call it `www.example.com`.

I load an iframe in `www.example.com` which is a PWA.

Is it possible to install the PWA in the iframe? If not, why?

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?  Here is the simplest sample PWA https://airhorner.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "install".

If you're asking whether an `<iframe>` can register a service worker, the answer is yes. That service worker will have its `install`/`activate` handlers fired in the same manner as it would as if it were a top-level document that registered the `<iframe>`. Just to be clear, the service worker and cache storage will be scoped to the origin of the `<iframe>`, not the top-level document.

If you're talking about whether loading a document in an `<iframe>` can meet the requirements for showing the "[Add to Homescreen](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/)" UI in Chrome, the answer is no. The `beforeinstallprompt` event should not be fired in that scenario.